# Generating unsigned apk in Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to generate unsigned apk in AS 2.1.1. I had it working on 1.5.1 but right now I can't get it right.

Approaches tried:

```
signingConfigs {

    unsigned {
        keyAlias ''
        keyPassword ''
        storePassword ''
    }
    ...
}

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned
            debuggable false
        } 
        ...
}
```

Also another approach with not specifiying the signingConfig at all.
None of these work and both return with error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateUnsignedSigning'.
>   Keystore file not set for signing config unsigned

Generation is done by starting "assemble" task on whole project. Executing assemble task from the main module tasks tree produces the same result.

Build tools:     buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
Gradle:        'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want an unsigned apk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create unsigned apk set null as signingConfig:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig null
        ...
    }
}
```